# System.Exception {"Syntax error at line 1: illegal data at start of file"}

Tags: c#, ironpython, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a C#/Lightswitch application that is meant to generate an xml file by way of python scripting.  I didn't write the scripts but I've tested them outside of the C# application using Python 2.7.1. and they work properly without errors.  Now inside of Visual Studio I have saved (linked & copied to output) the py files inside the server side project.  In C# I call the ASB_script.py shown here...

```
from ABuilder import ABuilder

# Specify the input and output file names
baseXMLFileName = 'as_func_base.xml'
outputFileName  = 'as_func_tP74.xml'
configFileName  = 'Config_File_Name.xml'

# Create ABuilder Instance
AS = ABuilder(baseXMLFileName, outputFileName, configFileName)

# Specify built-in sequences
globalChecks = AS.getGlobalChecks()
abort = AS.getAbortSequence()
more code.....
```

The reference at the top is defined in the ABuilder.py file which has also been saved in the project and looks like this....

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class ABuilder(object):

channelTypes = ['Inputs', 'Outputs', 'Calculations', '[Other]...']

def __init__(self, baseXMLFileName, outputFileName, configFileName):
    self.SequenceTime = 0

    self.outputFileName = outputFileName
    self.tree = ET.parse(baseXMLFileName)
    self.root = self.tree.getroot()
    self.root.set("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

    self.channelNames = []
    ctree = ET.parse(configFileName)
    #   croot = ctree.getroot()
    #   for elem in ctree.iter("Name"): 
    # more commented code
```

NEW POINT - When i execute this code it throws the System.Exception syntax error listed in the title of this post.  I neglected to point out in my first post that the Exeception occurs at the last line of the following code...(should look familiar)

```
case "RunPythonScript":

                    {
                        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
                        var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
                        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
                        searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Projects\Python\xml-generation-python\");
                        engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);

                        var mainfile = @"D:\Projects\Python\xml-generation-python\ASB_script_threePortProof.py";
                        var scope = engine.CreateScope();

                        // Execute  code
                        engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(mainfile).Execute(scope);
```

NEW POINT - I have figured out how to execute the py files in 'Interactive Mode' within the Visual Studio framework and they generate the xml properly, so i think the py and xml files are OK.

[image: Exception Error in Visual Studio]

Comment: I'll also mention that i can't figure out how to recreate the log that's shown in the above screenshot.  It may very well be that the configFileName is getting loaded with garbage but i'm having a hard time watching the variable.

Comment: The problem seems to be the xml file, not the python code. Please check the encoding and maybe recreate the xml file. You also could inspect it using some hex editor...

Answer (score 1):

If you created the file within Visual Studio, there's a good chance that it was saved with the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and is causing problems.  Visual Studio saves it this way by default.  Check the encoding of the file and save it without it.

To do so, open the file and go to the menu `File` -> `Advanced Save Options...` and change the `Encoding` to `Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001` (or whatever is appropriate) and save the file.

See if it causes problems then.